# How to make Image outline selectable

Tags: css, reactjs, image, shapes, outline

I have a country map with its region outlined on it as a single image. The React app I'm trying to create needs to be able to get the statistics of each region upon hovering on a specific region.

How can I make the regions on the map independent of the whole image so that individually I can get some information and also be able to color these regions may be based on some risks (statistics)?

I tried cutting the shapes of each region in Photoshop and then placing them over the original image in my web app but I can't seem to get going through with that.

Any idea of how I could achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: _"I tried cutting the shapes of each region in Photoshop and then placing them over the original image in my web app but I can't seem to get going through with that."_ - please elaborate on **exactly** what you did and exactly what you mean "can't seem to get going"

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CSS to position the images in a z-stacking context and adjust their opacity, or use CSS mask-images?

Comment: If possible, I would definitely go for an svg map. Kinda like [this](https://codepen.io/erikawithak/pen/BMzJYO?html-preprocessor=pug)

Comment: @Dai first off, the cuts aren't that good so when overlaying you can see it not being exactly the same. 2nd, I'm unable to put color to the inside of the cut image even though the inside is transparent so I just don't know where I am going with that idea

Comment: @Yarin_007 That link you sent is exactly the kind of stuff I would like to do. Any Idea how I could do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following HTML elements to split the map image into pieces:

- `<map>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map
- `<area>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Example:

```
<map name="map">
  <area
    shape="poly"
    coords="100,10,40,40,60,140,160,140,180,60"
    id="region1"
    onMouseEnter={() => yourActions('region1')}
  />

  <area
    shape="poly"
    coords="200,140,250,180,320,150,310,110,240,100"
    id="region2"
    onMouseEnter={() => yourActions('region2')}
  />
</map>
```

Comment: How do you figure the coords value for an area ?

Comment: Maybe I get you wrong but you can use an online tool, such as https://www.image-map.net/, that allows you to draw forms on a image. Just trying to find the coords probably won't work. I have tried polygons, and then the tool outputs the coords. I used an [image of a US map](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71xRXqkEHyL._AC_SL1380_.jpg), this was returned for a poly on Utah (randomly chosen :) ->  `coords="331,348,303,475,406,491,415,390,380,387,382,363" shape="poly">` - maybe an SVG map as linked in a comment above is the best option, not sure ...